# CSS How to apply outer class style to inner element having their own class

Tags: css

I have three styles declared :  A,B,C.

C is the last.

I have this :

```
<div class="C">
  < div class="A"> </div>
  < div class="B"> </div>
</div>
```

Why inner divs does not use class 'C' information ?
I want a way to apply C to all inner divs, regardless the inner class they have.

Maybe I have not fully understand css rules application?

Comment: it doesn't inherit styles by default. that's wat the `inherit` css value exists for. Why would you - for example - a button to inherit all the styles from it's parent container?

Comment: Note: many css properties _do_ inherit, such as `color`. Not all of them though.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<div class="C">
    <div class="A C"> </div>
    <div class="B C"> </div>
</div>
```

That way, child divs will inherit C properties, easily.

Comment: If you have many elements inside the C element, you can write `C *` for a selector in css.